# ScrollTop with offset not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've got an animate function in jQuery to scrollTop with an offset.
This works fine in safari and firefox but doesn't work in chrome.
This is my code:

```
$(".navbar-collapse ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

   // prevent default anchor click behavior
   e.preventDefault();

   // store hash
   var hash = this.hash;

   // animate
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -50
     }, 700, function(){

       // when done, add hash to url
       // (default click behaviour)
       window.location.hash = hash;
     });

});
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Provide the HTML to make it easier to test your code and see the issue you're having. Also your line `$(hash).offset().top -` ends with a minus (-), so are you trying to subtract something and forgot to type it there? If not, you need to remove the minus.